# Pandas Iterate over dataframe to relate cells via their related content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

The title may not be the full description of what I want to do, but I will try to fully explain what I am working with. I have a pandas Dataframe that contains all data from files in a directory.[image]

> ```
> >  Drive  Main             Project Imaging Folder Experimental Group  \
> > 0     Z:  koch  SARS-CoV-2 Project        Imaging     SmF_SCoV_5'UTR  
> > 1     Z:  koch  SARS-CoV-2 Project        Imaging     SmF_SCoV_5'UTR  
> > 79    Z:  koch  SARS-CoV-2 Project        Imaging     SmF_SCoV_5'UTR  
> > 80    Z:  koch  SARS-CoV-2 Project        Imaging     SmF_SCoV_5'UTR  
> > 91    Z:  koch  SARS-CoV-2 Project        Imaging     SmF_SCoV_5'UTR  
> > 92    Z:  koch  SARS-CoV-2 Project        Imaging     SmF_SCoV_5'UTR  
> > 
> > 
> >            Experimental Rep                        File Name  \ 0   20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR   mRNA_MAX_Cell09_Spot_Stats.csv    1  
> > 20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR   mRNA_MAX_Cell10_Spot_Stats.csv    79 
> > 20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR  AVG_BG_MAX_Cell10.tif (RGB).tif    80 
> > 20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR               AVG_MAX_Cell10.tif    91 
> > 20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR                   MAX_Cell09.tif    92 
> > 20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR                   MAX_Cell10.tif   
> > 
> >                                                  Path     7   0   Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'...   NaN   1  
> > Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'...   NaN   79 
> > Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'...  None   80 
> > Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'...  None   91 
> > Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'...  None   92 
> > Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'...  None
> ```

In this dataframe I have both csv files and tif files. I already have code that will read in all the csv files and I can access them based on file file name.

```
FINDPATH = Path("Z:\koch\Imaging")
FILEEXT = ("*.csv")

files_dfs = {}

for csv_file in FINDPATH.rglob(FILEEXT):
    filename = csv_file.name
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    files_dfs[filename] = df
```

Each of these csv files have a respective tif file. For instance mRNA_MAX_Cell09_Spot_Stats.csv comes from MAX_Cell09.tif.

I now need to come up with a way to iterate over the dataframe, take only the original tif file (all named MAX_Cell...), output the filepath, and finally get the respective csv File Name.

The goal is to be able to take the tif file and do in silico simulations and compare to the real data in the csv file.

I hope this is well explained. Any insight would be more than helpful.

Thank you

Comment: How are the TIF filenames related to the CSV filenames? So, for example, you give the example that "mRNA_MAX_Cell09_Spot_Stats.csv" is the CSV file for the "MAX_Cell09.tif" TIF file. Is it always true that the file "mRNA_MAX_CellNN_Spot_Stats.csv" corresponds to "MAX_CellNN.tif", where NN is some integer? If that's true, I would look into [Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The naming scheme will always remain the same between the tif and csv files.

Comment: Can you provide your data from the image in a copy-pastable dataframe? You can do this by doing `print(df)`, and copying it into the question.

Comment: I printed the dataframe into the original question. I hope that is the format that you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two steps here:

1. Get the cell number so we can match files belonging to the same experiment and cell number.
2. Use groupby() to perform the matching.

After that, you can loop over the groupby, and get rows belonging to a single experiment.

Example:

```py
s = """Drive,Main,Project,Imaging Folder,Experimental Group,Experimental Rep,File Name,Path
0,Z:,koch,SARS-CoV-2 Project,Imaging,SmF_SCoV_5'UTR,20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR,mRNA_MAX_Cell09_Spot_Stats.csv,Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'UTR\mRNA_MAX_Cell09_Spot_Stats.csv
1,Z:,koch,SARS-CoV-2 Project,Imaging,SmF_SCoV_5'UTR,20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR,mRNA_MAX_Cell10_Spot_Stats.csv,Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'UTR\mRNA_MAX_Cell10_Spot_Stats.csv
79,Z:,koch,SARS-CoV-2 Project,Imaging,SmF_SCoV_5'UTR,20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR,AVG_BG_MAX_Cell10.tif (RGB).tif,Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'UTR\AVG_BG_MAX_Cell10.tif (RGB).tif
80,Z:,koch,SARS-CoV-2 Project,Imaging,SmF_SCoV_5'UTR,20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR,AVG_MAX_Cell10.tif,Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'UTR\AVG_MAX_Cell10.tif
91,Z:,koch,SARS-CoV-2 Project,Imaging,SmF_SCoV_5'UTR,20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR,MAX_Cell09.tif,Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'UTR\MAX_Cell09.tif
92,Z:,koch,SARS-CoV-2 Project,Imaging,SmF_SCoV_5'UTR,20210424_CMV_SARS_5'UTR,MAX_Cell10.tif,Z:\koch\SARS-CoV-2 Project\Imaging\SmF_SCoV_5'UTR\MAX_Cell10.tif
"""
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))


# Extract the cell number in the filename of each file
df['Cell Num'] = df['File Name'].str.extract('Cell([0-9]+)[._]')
# Extract the filetype for each file
df['File Type'] = df['File Name'].str.extract('\\.([a-z]{2,4})')
# Keep only files which are either csv or tif files of the form MAX_CellNN.tif
df = df.loc[(df['File Type'] == 'csv') | (df['File Name'].str.match("MAX_Cell[0-9]+.tif"))]

for group_id, group_df in df.groupby(["Experimental Group", "Experimental Rep", "Cell Num"]):
    experimental_group, experimental_rep, cell_num = group_id
    print(experimental_group, experimental_rep, cell_num)
    file_group = group_df['File Name'].to_list()
    print(file_group)
```

(The first eight lines are just to make the example reproducible. You don't need them if you already have the dataframe.)

Comment: Thank you for the response. It looks really promising. I will look into it and test it with my work tomorrow. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: It seems to have worked great. I believe that I will be able to work from the outputs to get everything that I need. I am a little unfamiliar with the syntax on the str.extract. Could you briefly explain how this is working? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Adam str.extract uses [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract part of a string from each cell in a column, and add this extracted string as a new column. Specifically, the `()` characters form a "capture group." They identify what is captured. The syntax `[0-9]` is a "character class." The plus stands for one or more of the previous element. The capture group matches at least one digit character, surrounded by the literal text "Cell" on the left side, and either an `_` or a `.` on the other side. Take a look at [regex explainer](https://regexr.com/6apcl).